# how to switch from pack() to place() properly

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

i have my tkinter gui split in different classes and want to connect them in a home screen with buttons, like Steven M. Vascellaro did here: [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter?newreg=c3625a4dfc8043d193b9e07740961ea5)

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
#from alexa_site_2 import Frame_alexa
from globals import Globals
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.geometry('{}x{}'.format(1024, 600))
        self.configure(bg="white")
        for i in range(len(Globals.image_files)):
            image_box = PhotoImage(file=Globals.image_files[i])
            Globals.list_images.append(image_box)
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.place(x=110,y=0)
        print("switch frame function")

class StartPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #self.place(x=0,y=0)
        ttk.Label(self, text="This is the start page").pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Open page one",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Open page two",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageTwo)).pack()
    ttk.Button(self, text="Open page two",
      command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Frame_alexa)).pack()

class PageOne(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        ttk.Label(self, text="This is page one").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
              command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()

class PageTwo(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        ttk.Label(self, text="This is page two").place(x=40,y=10)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
              command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).place(x=0,y=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

when I try connect my own classes i get a white window as result. You can see it working in pageOne and my problem in PageTwo. I am not planning on mixing place() and pack(). I just need place() and your help please.

Comment: Why do you want to switch to `place`? Generally speaking, it will make it harder to create your code, and definitely much harder to get it to work on different platforms with different resolutions or different fonts.

Comment: Give **grid()** a try. Don't use place() for your problem.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. the thing is i am developing for just one screen size and i have written 100s of lines of code using the place manager. furthermore the grid manager has not been exact enough. this here would have been the last piece of the puzzle.